# C++ error "tabulate.cc:19: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token"

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to output a list of pairs of the form L:N where L is a line number and N is the number of occurrences of the given word.  I'm running into an error when I try to insert the string and the pair of of the occurrence and the line it occurs on: "tabulate.cc:19: error: expected primary-expression before ',' token"

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {

  ifstream myfile(argv[1]);
  map<string, pair<int, int> > freq;
  string word;
  int lc;

  while (myfile >> word) {
    while (getline(myfile, word)){
      lc++;
    }
    freq.insert(std::make_pair(word, std::make_pair(++, lc) ) );
  }

  map<string, pair<int,int> >::const_iterator iter;
  for (iter=freq.begin(); iter != freq.end(); ++iter) {
    cout << iter->first << " " << iter->second.first << " " << iter->second.second << endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
freq.insert(std::make_pair(word, std::make_pair(++, lc) ) );
                                                ^^ // What is being incremented here?
```

Answer (score 2):

You have `++, lc` here, please make sense out of it